# How to test a vue vuetify v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils, v-autocomplete

Somehow I'm not able to see the `items` of the `v-autocomplete` inside the html during the test and also setting an item does not work. Below the `v-autocomplete` (which is loading the items on mount) and the test.

```js
// v-autocomplete.vue
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    :items="items"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
  ></v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    service.getItems().then((response) => {
      this.items = response;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

The test looks like this:

```js
//v-autocomplete.spec.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import VAutocomplete from '@/components/v-autocomplete.vue';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import service from '@/service/service';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const items= [
  { name: 'Item 1', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Item 2', id: 2 },
];

const getItemsSpy = jest
  .spyOn(service, 'getItems')
  .mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(items);
    });
});


describe('v-autocomplete.vue', () => {
  let localVue;
  let vuetify;
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    localVue = createLocalVue();
    vuetify = new Vuetify();
  });

  it('should load the items', async () => {
    wrapper = mount(VAutocomplete, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
      propsData: {},
    });

    expect(getItemsSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    for (const item of items) {
      expect(getByText(wrapper.element, item.name)).toBeTruthy(); // Will fail -> Unable to find an element with the text
    }
  });
});
```

The test `expect(getByText(wrapper.element, item.name)).toBeTruthy();` will fail with the message `Unable to find an element with the text`. Also printing the html with `console.log(wrapper.html())` does not show the items of the `v-autocomplete`. So my question would be:

1. How could I test, if the items were loaded?
2. How could I set one of the loaded as the selected item of the `v-autocomplete`?

Answer (score -1):

You can open autocomplete menu on click `.v-input__slot`. I do no think, it is best practice to test library functionality.

Unit test:

```js
it("should load the items", async () => {
  wrapper = mount(VAutocomplete, {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
    propsData: {}
  });

  const autocomplete = wrapper.element;
  const autocompleteControls = autocomplete.find(".v-input__slot");

  autocompleteControls.trigger("click");
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

  expect(getItemsSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  for (const item of items) {
    expect(getByText(wrapper.element, item.name)).toBeTruthy();
  }
});
```

Source:
[https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/\_\_tests__/VSelect.spec.ts](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/%5C_%5C_tests__/VSelect.spec.ts)

Comment: The v-autocomplete is part of a form and the items were loaded form an external source. To submit the form I have to select one of the values. Therefore I need to know if something is loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately the provided solution does not work for me. I'm able to find the elements with `.findAll('.v-input__slot')` and trigger a click. But the html is not updated.

Comment: Can you add your package.json? I will tun couple more tests with your dependencies. Because, in console.log(wrapper.html()), I can see the menu items. The problem could also be in mocking items. Try to console.log(this.items) after your mounted.